# Python unwanted whitespace added to file

Tags: python, json

Wrote tests to be executed on my Python application.  The tests compare two files, expected outcome (static saved files) to the outcome (test-generated) using Python's filecmp. At first this worked perfectly.  Then as time went on the file stopped matching and tests started to fail.

If I do a Unix `diff` indeed the files are different yet the lines have the same content.  If I ignore whitespace, i.e. use the `diff -w` option, the files match.

```
bash-4.1$ diff -w myfile.out ../expected_outcome

bash-4.1$ diff  myfile.out ../expected_outcome | more
4,6c4,6
<       "file": "File1",
<       "name": "Myfile1",
<       "created": "07/06/2015",
---
>       "file": "File1", 
>       "name": "Myfile1", 
>       "created": "07/06/2015",
```

A co-worker suggested I look at the hex of my files and compare them:

```
outcome:
0000040: 7265 7669 7369 6165 2e65 7464 222c 200a  Myfile1", .

expected outcome:
0000040: 7265 7669 7369 6165 2e65 7464 222c 0a20  Myfile1",.

=> So you can see the last byte is different between the 
two files, i.e. 200a is not same as 0a20.
```

This is how I am currently writing my results to file:

```
rv = self.app.get(url)

with open(output_path1, 'w') as fp:
     fp.write(rv.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

In the Python docs it was not clear how requests returned data.  After some brainstorming with a co-worker we thought a way around this would be to to use json.dump to write the file specifying the separators.  Unfortunately I keep getting errors and would appreciate if someone could please correct my syntax:

```
rv = self.app.get(url)

with open(output_path1, 'w') as fp:
    data = json.load(rv.data.decode('utf-8'))
    json.dump(data, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Yields the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Why are you using `json.load()` on a string? You should use `json.loads()` in that case.

Comment: Also, `json.dump()` takes a file object as well as the data to dump. You need to pass in `fp`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the comments, yes I had two typos, below is the corrected code that works:

**code**

```
rv = self.app.get(url)
with open(output_path1, 'w') as fp:
    data = json.loads(rv.data.decode('utf-8'))
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=2, separators=(', ', ': '))
```